# MySQL data base folder backup

Tags: mysql

Before I formatted Windows I had copy of mysql55 folder in program data. After that I installed Mysql55 server and pasted that folder.

But I can't access my databases. What can I do to open that databases?

Comment: Have you restarted you DB serve after restoring the files?

Comment: when you copied your data, was the mysql server halted?